# Python Pandas check frequency of value combination under the same column in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

It is like I have a data frame. I groupby the ['ID', 'disease'] , in disease column there are more than 2 diseases
I want to know how to get the frequency of combination of disease.

```
id        disease
1         Aids
ADHD
2         Something
Aids
```

For example how do I know how many ID has disease combination of Aids and ADHD

I am expecting like getting a new column to have the frequency on.

Comment: Your formatting is unclear, please fix and give more details if the duplicate is not what you need

Comment: Hi, 
id        disease
1          A
            B
2          B
            C
This is the format, it pretty much is I want to know how many times, disease A and B happened to a patient

Comment: Ok, I just realized the spaces doesnt work so good. But for example, patient ID 1 has two disease in two rows of data, such as A and B. I want to know how I can calculate the patients that has disease A and B.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) carefully, improve your question accordingly, and we'll see how we can answer your question.